# Set Office Web Apps as a WebPart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, excel

Currently, I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013, and I want to config like the link below, but in foundation version, I cannot see "**Business data\Excel Web Access**"

[image]

So I setup Office Web Apps, but I do not know how to create a page and add a WebPart with display excel content like that.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of the Enterprise edition of SharePoint Server. This functionality will not be available to you with SharePoint Foundation. Office Web Apps is not a factor here.